# Situation with two datagridviews

Tags: vb.net

I have situation with two datagridviews on same form.
In first is "list of documents" and in second are data which belong to each document from the list organized in rows.

Both grids are .Readonly=TRUE and with ".SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect" and Multiselect=FALSE.
Both have AllowUserToAddRows to TRUE what makes that I have one blank row after last row for adding a new row.

Situation is that I have (say) 10 rows filled with documents in DatagridView1 and, at the end, one blank row. When I click to row 11 (empty row) my Datagridview1.CurrentRow.Index  is 10 since zero based index of rows.

But when I now click to second DataGridView my Datagridview1.CurrentRow.Index falls to 9 and little black triangle on the row headers jumps to last filled row automatically.

My program is such that I would need correct information of selected row in DataGridView1 when I try to enter to DataGridView2 even if selected row is blank or empty.

Can I avoid those automatic behaviour somehow that last selected row stays selected when DatagridView1 lost a focus?

Comment: Why would you want the last empty row to be selected ?

Comment: When I click into DataGridView2 I need to know which row is selected in DataGridView1. That may also be last (empty) row among all others. Is this so unusual?

Comment: What is the underlying datasource of each DGV?

Comment: PostgreSQL>NpgSqlDataAdapter>Dataset

Comment: I think the only/best way to do this is to set up the `DataGridView` in [VirtualMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: ... and always keep the `DataGridView.RowCount` one step ahead of the underlying datasource.

Comment: Show your code(if you have) of both datagridview's `.SelectedIndexChanged` event handler

Comment: Hi Fabio! I didn't use _SelectionChanged but _Paint handler to get selected row. _SelectionChanged solves this problem and program now behaves as expected, thank you.